# create hyper link to a specific location in pdf using mpdf

Tags: php, hyperlink, mpdf

until now I was using TCpdf to create pdf documents

and I used html href tags in order to create a refernce to a specific location inside the same document like this:

```
<a href="#' . $page . ',' . $y_loc . '">
```

which created an hyperlink that sent me to a specific page , and to a specific cordinate on that page.

I switched to mpdf,

how can I achive the same behiviour using mpdf? (using the same format doent work)
thx

Answer (score 4):

With mPDF it's similar to the way you would create an internal link in an HTML document. For the link text create a link like so:

```
<a href="#desired_content">Click here to jump to the content</a>
```

And then wrap the content in an  tag with no href, but with a name the same as the # one above. Like so:

```
<a name="desired_content">This is where your content goes.</a>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: well I also found this in their forumes.. but It didnt work for me, I found out that it wont work when document has rtl mixed with ltr in it.. no idea why, possibly a bug, I sent them a request about it